# Python tools/libraries for generating values from ParserFunctions in wikipedia

Tags: python, wikipedia

Given a piece of [Wikipedia ParserFunction](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions) text, are there any tools or libraries in Python to generate the computed value from the text? e.g.

```
>>> parserfunc_2_value('{{#expr: 1/3 round 5 }}')
0.33333
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dirty solution for `#expr` expressions: I found that a lot of expression with '#expr' share the same function name with library `math`. Then I use `eval` to get the value by the following function:

```py
import wikitextparser as wtp
import math
import re

def parserfunc_2_value(val='{{#expr: 1/3 round 5 }}'):
    eq = wtp.parse(val).parser_functions[0].arguments[0].value
    filter_pattern = [['([\d\*\/\+\-\s]*)?(round|div|mod)([\d\*\/\+\-\s]*)',r'\2(\1,\3)'],
     ['(trunc|abs|exp|ln|sin|cos|tan|acos|asin|atan)([\d\*\/\+\-\s]*)',r'\1(\2)'],
                      ['ln\(([\d\*\/\+\-\s]*)\)',r'log(\1)']]
    for ptn,rep in filter_pattern:
        eq = re.sub(ptn,rep,eq)
    return eval(eq)

parserfunc_2_value()
```

This function seems to be able to deal most of the simple patterns for `#expr`, here are some examples:

```
>>> parserfunc_2_value('{{#expr: 1/3 round 5 }}')
0.33333
>>> parserfunc_2_value('{{#expr: 1+4 }}')
5
```

Comment: That's... really dirty. If you want to write a proper parser, the MediaWiki code is [here](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-ParserFunctions/blob/master/includes/ExprParser.php). It's pretty straightforward and not too hard to replicate in Python.

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion, I will try to replicate it in Python.